# startWith filter with object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to work with `startWith` filter but it is not filtering the data correctly, like in case of `P`. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Controller code -

var app = angular.module('filterSample', []);
app.controller('filterCtrl', function ($scope) {

```
$scope.data = {
    messages: [
        {       
        "id":"111619EEVz",
        "name":"Tom 67",
        "status":"Pending"
        },
        {
            "id":"115419EEAA",
            "name":"Business 34",
            "status":"Pending"
        },
        {   
            "id":"1B167000WW",
            "name":"Jack 78",
            "status":"Active",
        }
    ]
  }

  $scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }
});
```

HTML -

```
<div ng-controller="filterCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
        <ul border="1px" ng-repeat="msg in data.messages | filter:search:startsWith">
          <li>{{msg.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Working Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/tByYZ3jpEk7YPpJnMY11?p=preview

Edit 1 -

Filtering should be like it should only search in `name` property rather than searching in whole object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change ng-model to search.name

```
<div ng-controller="filterCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" />
    <ul border="1px" ng-repeat="msg in data.messages | filter:search:startsWith">
      <li>{{msg.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx a lot, its working now..btw can you please explain about the behavior  :)

Comment: Please mark this as an answer. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter. Check the example there.